# Отследить потерю памяти Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, память

Помогите отследить потерю оперативной памяти. При каждом запуске отчета она увеличивается на 2-3 мб.
Вот как запускаю отчет

```
private void callLoading()
{
  loadingList f7 = new loadingList();
  f7.ShowDialog();
}
```

Код формы в которой открывается отчет

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace MSU
{
  public partial class loadingList : Form
  {
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"строка подключения");
    DandDDataSet r = new DandDDataSet();

    public loadingList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadingList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("тут запрос", cn);
        da.Fill(r, r.Tables[0].TableName);

        ReportDataSource mds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", r.Tables[0]);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
      }

      private void loadingList_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
      {
        main m = this.Owner as main;
        m.dis();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        this.Dispose(true);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `cn.Open();` - вижу, `cn.Close();` - не вижу

Comment: Для вставки кода в вопрос добавляйте перед каждой строчкой кода 4 пробела

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, действительно не закрыл, но на ситуацию это никак не повлияло. Запускаю отчет оперативка с потребления 22мб прыгает до 31мб, закрываю, падает до 29мб, открываю прыгает до 33мб, закрываю, падает до 31мб, открываю прыгает до 36, закрываю, падает до 33мб. Ну и так далее до упора можно открывать закрывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Победил пожирание оперативной памяти вот так :

```
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"строка"))
          {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
               using (DandDDataSet m = new DandDDataSet())
                {
                  using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("тут запрос", cn))
                   {
                    da.Fill(r, r.Tables[0].TableName);

                    ReportDataSource mds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",r.Tables[0]);
                    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds);
                    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

                    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();  
                   }
               }  
           }  
         }
```

Мне писали что не нужен метод при закрытии формы, но как раз он и подчищает

```
  private void loadingList_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {            
     this.reportViewer1.Reset();
     this.reportViewer1.Dispose();
     GC.SuppressFinalize(reportViewer1);
     GC.Collect();  
  }
```

Comment: 1. В вопросе у вас другой код. 2. Этот код (если он действительно нужен) должен находиться в `Dispose()` формы, а не в `FormClosing`.

Answer (score 3):

Закрытие модальной формы всего лишь [прячет ее](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c7ykbedk.aspx). А значит, форма остается в памяти. При использовании метода `ShowDialog()` нужно всегда вызывать `Dispose()`. Исправить легко:

```
private void callLoading()
{
    using (loadingList f7 = new loadingList())
    {
        f7.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Также стоит помнить, что тот факт, что вы с каждым открытием видите все увеличивающееся количество занятой памяти, вовсе не означает наличие утечки! CLR может и не собирать мусор некоторое время, если на то нет необходимости. Наличие утечки может показать только профайлер, в котором вы снимите и сравните два снэпшота ДО и ПОСЛЕ.

---

Бонус:

- Уберите метод `loadingList_FormClosing()`. Он не нужен. Совсем.
- `SqlConnection` является ограниченным ресурсом, поэтому его лучше всего закрывать и освобождать сразу, как вы закончили с ним работать. К счастью, для `SqlConnection` можно вызвать только `Dispose()`, коннекция при этом закроется автоматически:

  ```
  private void loadingList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"строка подключения"))
      {
          cn.Open();
          //остальной код
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Если верить этому - http://www.sql.ru/forum/1087139/utechka-pamyati-pri-ispolzovanii-komponenta-reportviewer, то ето болезнь самой библиотеке `reportviewer`. Я сделал как вы порекомендовали но ничего не изменилось, где мне нужно использовать `Dispose()`?

Comment: @Winteriscoming тем не менее, даже если бы ReportViewer не тек, у вас все равно были бы утечки :). Смотрите тогда дальше по ссылкам, что делать с ReportViewer.

Comment: @Winteriscoming конструкция [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx) уже вызывает `Dispose()`.

Comment: диалог и должен только прятаться, т.к. может содержать заполненные свойства после работы. Вообще не стоит пересоздавать диалог перед каждым вызовом, поместите ссылку на него в поле родительской формы и вызывайте через это поле.

Comment: @rdorn пожалуйста по подробнее, как это сделать покажите пример, буду очень благодарен если поможет, я 2 день не могу найти решения как бороться с reportViewer. За один запуск -3мб оперативы, при закрытии высвобаждает максимум 1мб.

Comment: @rdorn зависит от сценария использования. Мне таким заниматься ни разу не приходилось.

Comment: @andreycha если диалог нужен один раз, тогда да, не спорю. А если он нужен относительно постоянно, вроде диалогов открытия или сохранения файлов, то его проще зафиксировать и не думать, создан он или нет. Да и шаблоны MS используемые в конструкторе ту же идеологию продвигают, понятно что это еще не показатель, они под каждый контрол поле создают, но тем не менее факт. А так-то у вас все уже написано, ну хочет автор, добавлю небольшой пример.

Comment: @andreycha пример, который вы написали как бонус, опасно ли будет если я строку подключение зашью в public string и буду ее использовать везде где открываю подключение, что бы постоянно не прописывать строку подключения, не сможет ли ее кто то перехватить? Еще вопрос, неужели способ, который вы описали более продуктивный чем просто cn.Open() в начале кода и cn.Close в конце при этом количество самого кода будет меньше? Я новичок.

Comment: @Winteriscoming смогут просто декомпилировать ваш код и посмотреть значение вашей константы. От чего вы пытаетесь защититься? Насчет коннекции все просто: если запомнить правило "одноразовый disposable объект оборачивай в using", то отпадает необходимость каждый раз помнить о вызове метода `Dispose()`/`Close()` с использованием `try/finally`. Да и сам `using` выглядит чуть более элегантно, чем `try/finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Большую часть уже описал **@andreycha** в своем ответе.

Если диалог используется достаточно часто в приложении, то можно не создавать его заново каждый раз, как он потребовался. Для этого разместим нужный диалог в форме которая его будет использовать. В этом нет ничего сложного, но раз уж попросили, пусть будет в виде ответа.

```
public partial MyForm : Form
{
  private loadingList _loadingList;
  ...
  public loadingList()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _loadingList = new loadingList();
    //настраиваем параметры диалога если надо
    ...
    private void callLoading()
    {
      loadingList.ShowDialog();
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Важно! Если утечка памяти в коде самого диалога или компонента внутри него, то такой подход может только ухудшить ситуацию, т.к. "подтекающий" компонент будет в памяти постоянно и, соответственно, ресурсы тоже будут течь постоянно.

---

Если так уж важно освободить память, можно вызвать `GC.Collect()`, но делать это надо осторожно, т.к. GC приостанавливает все потоки приложения на время сборки мусора и реальная необходимость в прямом обращении к GC бывает не так часто, например при работе с очень большими объектами, от которых нужно избавиться заранее чтобы не поймать OutOfMemoryException (из личной практики, другого варианта просто не было). Ради пары-тройки мегабайт явно не стоит, и от реальной утечки памяти это тоже не поможет.

Comment: Утечка внутри окна, перед вызовом окна потребление памяти 23мб, вызвали окно память не изменилась, но как только нажимаем кнопку просмотреть отчет, reportviewer вытягивает инфу и сходу пожирает 10мб после закрытия не освобождает, последующее открытие отчета поджирает 1-3мб и не освобождает. GC.Collect() - не помогает, возможно я не в том участке ставил? Я ставил тут       `private void loadingList_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
}`

Comment: @Winteriscoming если с английским дружите, посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/6221590/5796587, перевод могу сделать но скорее всего только в выходные, если больше ни кто не соберется.

Comment: я пробовал описанные способы, мне не помогло, как впрочем и многим людям, которые оставляли комментарии под этим решением. Я мягко говоря в отчаянии.

Comment: правильно ли я сделал? это в файле конфига - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="тут строка подключения"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>`

Comment: Это в форме генерации отчета - 

                da.Fill(r, r.Tables[0].TableName);

                ReportDataSource mds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", r.Tables[0]);
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds);
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);

Comment: я бы на вашем месте прошелся профайлером и посмотрел что именно остается в памяти лишнего и кто мешает это удалить. Может оказаться что проблема не там где ищете.

Comment: посоветуйте профайлер, понятный нубу =)

Comment: это на вкус и цвет. вот тут https://www.nprofiler.com/ есть список видимо, наиболее известных или популярных, и сравнение. Сравнению я не особенно верю, хоть и не проверял, но как минимум 4 профайлера разной степени доступности предложены. Тут еще можно почитать про встроенный в студию https://habrahabr.ru/post/98361/